# Converting list of Characters to Named num in R

Tags: r, class, dataframe, statistics, correlation

I want to create a dataframe with 3 columns.

```
#First column
name_list = c("ABC_D1", "ABC_D2", "ABC_D3", 
              "ABC_E1", "ABC_E2", "ABC_E3",
              "ABC_F1", "ABC_F2", "ABC_F3")

df1 = data.frame(C1 = name_list)
```

These names in column 1 are a bunch of named results of the cor.test function. The second column should consist of the correlation coefficents I get by writing ABC_D1$estimate, ABC_D2$estimate.

My problem is now that I dont want to add the $estimate manually to every single name of the first column. I tried this:

```
df1$C2 = paste0(df1$C1, '$estimate')
```

But this doesnt work, it only gives me this back:

```
"ABC_D1$estimate", "ABC_D2$estimate", "ABC_D3$estimate", 
"ABC_E1$estimate", "ABC_E2$estimate", "ABC_E3$estimate",
"ABC_F1$estimate", "ABC_F2$estimate", "ABC_F3$estimate")

class(df1$C2)
[1] "character
```

How can I get the numeric result for ABC_D1$estimate in my dataframe? How can I convert these characters into Named num? The 3rd column should constist of the results of $p.value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out  by @DSGym there are several problems, including the it is not very convenient to have a list of character names, and it would be better to have a list of object instead.

Anyway, I think you can get where you want using:

```
estimates <- lapply(name_list, function(dat) {
                          dat_l <- get(dat)
                          dat_l[["estimate"]]
                          }
                            )

cbind(name_list, estimates)
```

**This is not really advisable** but given those premises...

Comment: Yes that is working! Thanks! May I ask how would you do it instead if that solution is not very common.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think now i know what you need.

```
eval(parse(text = paste0("ABC_D1", '$estimate')))
```

You connect the two strings and use the functions `parse` and `eval` the get your results.

This it how to do it for your whole data.frame:

```
name_list = c("ABC_D1", "ABC_D2", "ABC_D3", 
              "ABC_E1", "ABC_E2", "ABC_E3",
              "ABC_F1", "ABC_F2", "ABC_F3")

df1 = data.frame(C1 = name_list)

df1$C2 <- map_dbl(paste0(df1$C1, '$estimate'), function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
```

Comment: Thank you! I know that paste0(ABC_D1, '$estimate') connects 2 strings, that is what I wanted to do, because it gives me the correct string then. My problem is that it is shown as character in the column. When I only write ABC_D1$estimate I get a number like 0.2. Also when I create a list like this: l1 = c(ABC_D1$estimate, ABC_D2$estimate, ABC_D3$estimate) I get 3 numbers. That is what I want, but when I use the paste0 command I get characters instead of the numbers.

Comment: Sorry! I found a mistake in my post. I meant paste0(ABC_D1, '$estimate')! And not paste0(df1$C1, '$estimate')!

Comment: So there already exists models? for exampled stored as ABC_D1$estimate?

Comment: Yes! I did this: ABC_D1= cor.test(Data1$Tempmax, Data2$Tempmax, method = "spearman") So ABC_D1 contains the results of cor.test, which I can get with ABC_D1$estimate or ABC_D1$pvalue.

Comment: updated my answer, guess this is what you need? :-)

Comment: Ok thanks! That already helps me! But how can I do that now for every single element of the name_list in Column 1?

Comment: the functions are vectorized, so you can apply them to the whole column. But to be honest, I would think about using a higher order function to store the results of your models in a vector instead of doing it this way.

Comment: Thanks! But this gives me the same number for each row.

Comment: Ok what I did not know: parse is not vectorized! `map_dbl` is from the `purrr` package

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and patience! Its working now!